# Access Variables from FXML and Scene Builder

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I've made a couple of custom components with FXML and Scene Builder which work great. For example, I have a component (SliderVariable) in which I have a Label, a Slider, a TextField and a previously made InfoIcon component (see image below). The InfoIcon is imported as a .jar file.

[image]

I can change the title, default text etc. of the SliderVariable within my java code wherever I use the SliderVariable. I was wondering however how I would go about accessing these variables from Scene Builder or FXML. What I want basically is that whenever I import my SliderVariable to a new project I want to be able to set its title, default text etc. from within Scene Builder. I've been searching for ages, is it even possible?

So to exemplify, this works:

```
    SliderVariable slider = new SliderVariable();
    Scene scene = new Scene(slider);
    slider.setTip("Tippety tip");
```

This does not:

```
  <InfoIcon fx:id="info" tipText="Tippety tip"/>
```

Why is this? Also here is the controller of the imported InfoIcon component:

```
public class InfoIcon extends StackPane {

    @FXML private Tooltip tip;

    public InfoIcon() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                "InfoIcon.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    public void setTipText(String value) {
        tip.textProperty().set(value);
    }
}
```

Many Thanks.

Comment: Do you also have a `getTipText()` and a `tipTextProperty()` method? I think the `FXMLLoader` may look for those methods to identify a property...

Comment: No I don't, I will give that a try, thank you!

Comment: Sorry, one more thing. Is there a way to make these options visible in Scene Builder?

Comment: Not one that I know of. There are others active on this forum with more knowledge of scene builder... Did adding the other methods make it work with FXML though?

Comment: It did and I managed to make the properties visible in Scene Builder as well. I am ecstatic. Maybe I should post my own solution. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Absolutely post your solution. It will be helpful to other users.